# How to control search result ordering

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search, sorting

Lets say someone searches for "item a" , and 20 items show up, is there a way to control which item shows up first and which item shows up second and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Not with the default search mechanism in Magento CE. In "fulltext" and "combined" mode the search results are ordered by relevance with:

```
MATCH (data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

- Source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php#L46
- Explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

In "like" mode, the search results are not ordered at all.

- Source: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php#L381